# WooCommerce: Hide all statuses except 'completed' on admin orders page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having trouble figuring out where I can edit the admin order page so it will hide all filters and only loop through the completed orders.

I appreciate any help to guide me on the right direction.

Comment: You need to find the hook, what is listing the orders, and then create your custom function for that. Don't forget the pagination too! http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a hook or filter anywhere in the docs for what I'm looking for. Perhaps it's not even an option to modify it.